# An error message occurred while tring to optimize my linear model based on the AIC

Tags: r

When I was working on my R project the other day and tried to optimize my linear model based on the AIC (using backward selection), I was stopped by an error message like this:

```
Error in stepAIC(lm(x ~ y + z), direction = "back") : 
number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
```

Do you have any idea what may be the problem here?

Comment: see the `Note` in `?stepAIC`: "We suggest you remove the missing values first".  See `?na.omit`.

Comment: How can I do the na.omit. Within this r command.      > fit5<-lm(healthscore~sex+age.centalized+education+migration+unemployed+logIncome+BMI+smoking+sport)
> summary(fit5)

Comment: you should put your data into a data frame, run `na.omit()` on the data frame, and pass it to `lm` via the `data` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me ,, it worked and finally I fined my best model ..

Comment: if you found the answer correct and useful, you can upvote it and/or click on the check mark next to it to accept it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(healthscore,sex,age.centralized,education,
    migration,unemployed,
    logIncome,BMI,smoking,sport)
fit5 <- lm(healthscore~.,data=na.omit(dat))
summary(fit5)
stepAIC(fit5)
```